# find all nodes with a given label and property using the neo4j java API

Tags: java, neo4j

I know about the findNodesByLabelAndProperty method of the GraphDatabaseServiceObject, but that method requires a value parameter.  In my case, I only want to know if there are any (1 or more) nodes in my database that have a specified label and property, but I don't know anything about the value of the property other than it's type. Any ideas?

Thanks
Howard

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you mean by "find a property only by type"?   What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am storing a number of different sets of nodes (sub-graphs) in a single neo4j database.  Each node in a given sub-graph has the same label, for example "test_network_1".  In order to add relationships to the nodes in a given sub graph, we run various similarity routines, for example "overlap-1" and the unique id (from a mongo database) of the exact run of the similarity algorithm is stored as a key of a property of the node. The values isn't important, but what is important is that I don't store the the results of the same analyses twice. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 2.0 you could use the method getAllNodesWithLabel from class org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.

```
GlobalGraphOperations.getAllNodesWithLabel(DynamicLabel.label("<label_name>"))
```

For more information: http://neo4j.com/api_docs//2.0.0-M06/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html#getAllNodesWithLabel(org.neo4j.graphdb.Label)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question correctly, but I would just create another (boolean-valued) property for the purpose of finding the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another node to store these kinds of counts- a single one with multiple properties such as "nodesWithLabelXAndPropertyY" with the count as the value which you can set at the end of your algorithm run. Or just a boolean exists/not exists value.
Then all you need to do is query this node for summary statistics.